# Remove all space between Devexpress ChartControl panes

Tags: c#, devexpress

I'm currently working with a DevExpress ChartControl with several panes stacked vertically on top of each other. The panes can individually be shown or hidden at runtime, but their contents won't change after they're created. I'd like to remove all space between the panes so that the border of each is totally flush with the border of the pane above/below it.

I've already used the following code to set the PaneDistance to 0, which normally would do exactly what I'm looking for:
`XYDiagram diagram = chartControl1.Diagram as XYDiagram;
diagram.PaneDistance = 0;`

However, the problem I'm running into, visible in the screenshow below, is that the labels on my y axes can sometimes extend vertically above or below the edge of the pane itself, which forces there to be space between my panes.

[image]

The first two panes have no space between them at all, which is exactly what I want, but the problem can be seen on the bottom whree panes. The "0" label on the second pane extends slightly below the table, so empty space is added to allow it to fit. The bottom two axes **both** have labels that extend outside their panes, so even **more space** is being added.

I've tried editing every property of these axes that I can think of, but nothing has been able to remove this blank space. It seems like just getting the outer labels to be pushed up or down so they're inside the pane height should do the trick. Anyone have any ideas on how I can get this working like it should?

**Edit:** I'll mention that in a different part of this app, I have a different set of panels, rotated and aligned horizontally, with their axis labels doing what I want them to do in the case above:

[image]

You can see that the "0" and "300" labels are shifted slightly off-center to fit within their own pane, so they don't extend out and create empty space. I didn't have to touch any code to get that to happen. It could be because these are all instances of the same axis, while the ones that don't do this are different axes, that causes them to play nice in this case?

**Edit 2:**

Here's what I've got after setting my axis `SideMarginsValue`s to 0 and `AlwaysShowZeroLevel` to false.  Getting closer!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

if you can't achieve what you need with DX chart's public properties there is still one trick you can try.

In Browser choose Inspect the chart area (CTRL+SHIFT+I in Chrome) and find the actual chart's element or the parent element and see what classes/ids DX have assigned to them.

[image: inspect DX chart element]

Then pick the nearest element class/id and try to play with it's css by assigning negative margins/paddings like:

```
.dxtcLite.dxtc-top .dxtc-stripContainer {
        margin-botton: -2px!important;
}
```

This is of course a dirty solution but sometimes it's the only one which works.

However, if you don't have any HTML-type margin/padding between chart panes but the blank space is actually a part of the generated chart Image, then probably the only thing you can do is to continue playing with DX chart properties which affect the actual chart image generation.

**UPDATE:**

Have you tried setting the [Range.SideMarginsValue](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#CoreLibraries/DevExpressXtraChartsRange_SideMarginsValuetopic) property to 0?

```
diagram.AxisY.WholeRange.SideMarginsValue = 0;
```

Another option would be to try to always hide 0-level axis label using 
[WholeRange.AlwaysShowZeroLevel](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#CoreLibraries/DevExpressXtraChartsWholeRange_AlwaysShowZeroLeveltopic) :

```
diagram.AxisY.WholeRange.AlwaysShowZeroLevel = false;
```

or try setting max values for the axis values to exclude border labels:

```
// depending on possible min/max values for each pane 
diagram.AxisY.WholeRange.SetMinMaxValues(5,  35 );
```

Let me know if anything of the above helps.

Comment: The combination of setting SideMarginsValue to 0 and AlwaysShowZeroLevelgets extremely close to what I want! The issue with the lower 0 label is solved, but unfortunately the upper label (like the 40,000 in my first screenshot) can still potentially show up and create some space. I also wish I could avoid removing side margins causing my bars to crash right into the top of their panes, but I can live with it (although being able to set upper and lower margins would be great...). I'll keep playing with the MinMaxValues though, I'll bet there's a way to solve the rest of this that way...

Comment: @jmatula you control the data which you send to chart control, correct? what if you try to get that upper boundary value before binding chart to data and set the SetMinMaxValues with a somewhat smaller max value to have the upper label not displayed? Sorry, didn't see your full comment. Yes, play with min/max axis labels values. If the answer was somehow helpful, would appreciate a vote up. Thanks.

Comment: @jmatula I've checked some of my charts and noticed that in addition to PaneDistance=0 they also have LabelsResolveOverlappingMinIndex attribute set, e.g.: `<cc1:XYDiagram PaneDistance="0" LabelsResolveOverlappingMinIndent="-2">` . So, maybe you can try setting/changing that one too.

Comment: Unfortunately that attribute (`diagram.Label.ResolveOverlappingOptions.MinIndent` in C#) doesn't seem to help in this case. Looks to me like it deals with overlapping labels on the same axis, but not on different ones. Good suggestion though!